# How to apply custom font icon shapes in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to show some custom shapes through font icons in my UWP project. I have created my own `.ttf` file for custom shapes. But I don't know how to apply it programmatically.

```
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
string font = "Assets/mycustomfont.webfont.ttf#MyCustomFont";
text.FontFamily= new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily(font);                    
this.grid1.Children.Add(text);
```

Anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Your code looks good to me, so I think the error could be somewhere in the string where you describe where your font is and the variant e.g. MyCustomFont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you are using is practically correct, but make sure to check the following:

1. The `.ttf` file must be included in the project and have **Build Action** set to **Content** in the **Properties** window
2. Start the path to the font with `/` to make sure it begins in root.
3. Ensure the `#` suffix actually matches the font metadata. A font viewer app like [dp4 Font Viewer](https://us.fontviewer.de/) can help you with that. Use the Font Family name as the suffix.

I have [written an article on my blog](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/01/using-custom-fonts-in-cs-uwp-apps/) about using custom fonts in UWP so check it out to see if you haven't missed some of the steps there.

Comment: I want to show some custom icons on the textblock. Can you please explain how to do it.? Need to give like  textBlock.Text = "IconName"; .?

Comment: You basically need to find out what the character code for the font glyph is and use it (assign the `Text` to the unicode value). For example in Font Awesome, "\uf007" is the user icon glyph. You can use the dp4 Font Viewer to check the unicode values for the icons which you will then use in code.